# FormsAuthantication sign out

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net application, and I am using FormsAuthantication. When the user closes the page, the code located in Global.asax Session_End is executed : FormsAuthantication.SignOut(); 
But the problem is, session is not ending, if the user tries to open a page with cookie, the page shouldn’t be opened. User must be redirected to login page, but its not.
What can I do, what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a boolean variable and set a value while logging out, and write it into cookie. And then use that variable in page at cookie reading. If the user push sign out, set it true, if user closes browser it will be false. Declare default value false.